# send file to remote folder powershell

Tags: powershell

this is what i would use for copying without asking for password, because i want to schedule this script

```
    $Source = "d:\test\myZipFile.zip"
    $Dest   = "\\REMOTE_ip\D$\test"
    $Username = "Administrator"
    $Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "PasswordOFRemotePC" -AsPlainText -Force
    $mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($Username, $Password)
    
    New-PSDrive -Name J -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $Dest -Credential $mycreds -Persist
    Copy-Item -Path $Source -Destination "d:\test\myZipFile1.zip"
```

But it gives me error

> > New-PSDrive : The network resource type is not correct At D:\test\copy.ps1:7 char:1
>
> - New-PSDrive -Name J -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $Dest -Credential $m ...
> - ```
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (J:PSDriveInfo) [New-PSDrive], Win32Exception
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotMapNetworkDrive,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSDriveCommand
>   ```

Comment: Your source and destination on the Copy-Item cmdlet are the same. Simply use `-Destination $Dest` and make sure the user running the scheduled task has write permissions there and has read access on the source. No need for the New-PSDrive cmdlet.

Comment: Mistake was at last part ""d:\test\myZipFile1.zip"",i there must use my mapped drive "J:\myZipFile1.zip"

Comment: Ok, but still.. WHY the need for a mapping when you have the fully qualified UNC name to copy the file to? Again, make sure the user running the scheduled task has access to both the source and the destination

Comment: @Theo cause i didnt find any solution within that you said, these seems to me working as last option

Answer (score 0):

Going by the title of your question, I think you are overdoing this.

In your scheduled task, decide which user account should be running the script. That user should have Read access to the machine's local `D:\Test` folder and must have Write/Modify permissions to the remote path `\\REMOTE_ip\D$\test`.
You can set the task so that particular user does not even have to be logged in.

The executable to run is PowerShell.exe and the arguments are `-File <PathToTheScript.ps1>`
(for that, the task-running user must have Read & Execute permissions on the location of the script file)

The script itself can then be as simple as:

```
$Source = "d:\test\myZipFile.zip"
$Dest   = "\\REMOTE_ip\D$\test"

Copy-Item -Path $Source -Destination $Dest -Force
```